# ZF2 - The requested URL could not be matched by routing

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, routes, zend-framework2

i receive this error when i go to

localhost/app/public/spanel/test/index

This application have a sPanel module. Into it have a TestController with indexAction()

This is the sPanel\config\module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'sPanel\Controller\Test' => 'sPanel\Controller\TestController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'spanel' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/test[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'sPanel\Controller\Test',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'spanel' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I think you did not added your module 'sPanel' to application.config.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all i strongly suggest that you start working with virtual hosts to get rid of that annoying `localhost/bla/public`

Second of all things, you try to access this route: `yourdomain/spanel/test/index`, but there is no indication of you assigning the part `/spanel` anywhere in your route, all you assign is `/test[...]`

So in short, you want to access `yourdomain/test/index` or you want to modify your route to inclide the `/spanel` part

Comment: There are stupid questions, but this is none of them ;) You'd be surprised by how many mistakes have trouble understanding routing...